# Remover caracteres especiais mantendo os acentos

Tags: php, string, acentuação, preg-replace

Tenho essa função abaixo:

```
<?php
    $titulo = "Notícia Com Ácêntös";
    $titulo_novo = preg_replace(array('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/', '/[ -]+/', '/^-|-$/'),  array('', '-', ''), $titulo);
    
    echo $titulo_novo; // Retorna: Notcia-Com-cnts
?>
```

Notem que ela está removendo os acentos, eu quero que só remova os caracteres especiais, mas mantenha os acentos e `ç` (cedilha).

Preciso dessa função para renomear as imagens que faço o upload, por exemplo:

Converter isso:

```
"Símbolo cachaça & foguete.com.jpg"
```

Para isso:

```
"Símbolo-cachaça-foguete-com.jpg"
```

Comment: Para o resultado esperado me parece que nem de regex você precisa, bastaria talvez usar o https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtr.php, lembrando de separar a extensão do resto da string, o que pode ser feito com `pathinfo` ou até substr + strrpos

Comment: Dessa forma eu teria que identificar tudo o que eu quero substituir, quero alguma coisa automática que eu fale o que eu quero que não altere, e todo o resto suma. acho que o preg_replace é o ideal mas não estou fazendo direito.

Comment: Não me parece o ideal, só esta lhe parecendo isso porque resolveu parte do que você já queria, de qualquer forma o que eu disse já se aplica, mesmo em preg_replace, basta você DELIMITAR o que precisa que seja removido, ao invés de "ignorar", basta fazer o replace de &, _, . e espaços e por fim quando ficar se ficar hifens em sequencia faça um outro replace só para remover as sequencias que irão surgir.

Comment: Olha só, usei o exemplo do "&","." só como exemplo mesmo, pois tem uma infinidades de caracteres que os usuários podem nomear as imagens antes de enviar, pra eu fazer uma lista de todos o código iria ficar muito grande, entendeu?

Comment: Acentos utf8 e latin1 (iso-8859-1, windows-1252, etc) não são os mesmos, quero dizer `á` do utf--8 não é a mesma coisa que `á` do latin1, se parecem, mas não são iguais. Logo a própria ideia que aplicar algo da forma que você deseja vai ser algo falho, portanto não tem como resolver dessa forma que você deseja.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Criei um exemplo, isso que gostaria?

```
$titulos = [
    'Notícia ÷ 2×2 äëïöü',
    'Notícia Com Ácêntös',
    'Símbolo cachaça & foguete.com'
];

foreach($titulos as $titulo) {
    $novo_titulo = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{M}]+/u', '-', $titulo);
    
    echo $novo_titulo . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Exemplo: [aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d702d3c513352a7d4e090ce87b339b18bf3d7d0)

Comment: Olá Jeff. Se o script PHP for salvo com windows-1252 ou equivalente e os arquivos .jpg no sistema operacional estiverem com seus nomes em UTF-8, isso irá falhar. cc @AlexFonseca

Comment: Não querendo ser chato (mas fazer o quê... toda resposta é referência para futuros visitantes) mas só funcionou no teste por mera coincidência. O encoding do source é o primeiro problema de todos e não foi considerado. Fora isso, a regex está errada, além de deixar passar caracteres especiais que ficam entre `À` e `ü` ) Exemplo: `÷` https://ideone.com/e2KQMU. Você pode [edit] o post e corrigir os problemas a qualquer momento, um dos princípios do site é sempre dar espaço para melhorar os posts e agregar pra comunidadee). E, em unicode ainda tem a falta de normalização.

Comment: Sem levar em conta os problemas de encoding já mencionados, daria para "simplificar" para `preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{M}]+/u', '-', $titulo)`. O *lookahead* me parece desnecessário, pois para negar um caractere basta `[^...]` - e usei as [Unicode Properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) para pegar letras e diacríticos (os acentos, caso a string esteja em NFD). Claro que ainda não resolve o caso do `algo.com.jpg` que pelo exemplo da pergunta deveria ficar `algo-com.jpg` (somente o último ponto não é trocado), mas já melhora um pouco...

Comment: Olá pessoal, de fato a regex anterior não cobria todo o range que necessitava. Muito obrigado @hkotsubo pela sua contribuição.

Comment: Sobre o problema de encoding realmente pode acontecer. quais opções teriam para resolver esse problema? Infelizmente não consigo ajudar sem efetuar alguns testes e entender o cenário :/

Answer (score -4):

Obrigado @Jeff.Dev
Era exatamente o que eu queria, só dei uma minimizada nele e pronto, ficou perfeito!

```
<?php
$removerEspeciais = 'Notícia Com Ácêntös';
$removerEspeciais = preg_replace(['#(?![A-Za-zÀ-ü0-9.]).#i', '#[-]{1,}#i'], ['-', '-'], $removerEspeciais);
echo $removerEspeciais;
?>
```